# Send data using NetworkStream

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream

In my windows service I need to stream data to a tcp server. I declared a global TcpClient and NetworkStream and initiate them when the service starts. 
Every 30 seconds I go through an array of about 30-40 strings to send to the tcp server.

The send method looks like this:

```
    private void sendMessage(string message)
    {
            Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            Globals._stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            if (Globals._responseEnabled)
            {
                data = new Byte[256];
                String responseData = String.Empty;

                Int32 bytes = Globals._stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

                if (Globals._logStream)
                    Globals._el.writeEventToWindowsLog("Received: " + responseData, "Info");
            }
    }
```

Problem is that every 30 seconds only a few packets are sent with all of the strings combined inside, I want the strings to be sent in one packet each.

So how do I get the NetworkStream.write method to send the packet immediately? If I declare a new TCPClient and NetworkStream each time I call the send method (about 60times per minute) the data is sent seperately, but thats not a very nice solution. I tried NetworkStream.flush but that wasnt working..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the [NoDelay property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.nodelay.aspx) on the TcpClient to `true`;

> When NoDelay is false, a TcpClient does not send a packet over the
>   network until it has collected a significant amount of outgoing data.
>   Because of the amount of overhead in a TCP segment, sending small
>   amounts of data is inefficient. However, situations do exist where you
>   need to send very small amounts of data or expect immediate responses
>   from each packet you send.

Since you're wrapping it in a stream, you may still need to flush the stream to send immediately.